# Parsing table from NCBI BLASTp

Tags: python, perl, awk, blast

I would like to transform a two column file into a table of zero and ones, in order to be ready to PCA (principal component analysis). Input file is composed by bacteria name in the first column and bacteria descriptor in the second column.

Possible way: store input file in a hash, then do some kind of 'uniq' command on each column and add them to output file. To finish, for each combination in output file, add 0 or one if bacteria name and the descriptor are found in the file 1 hash.

Input file (tab-delimited):

```
bacteria_1  protein:plasmid:149679
bacteria_1  protein:proph:183386
bacteria_2  protein:proph:183386
bacteria_3  protein:plasmid:147856
bacteria_3  protein:proph:183386
```

Desired output (tab-delimited):

```
    protein:plasmid:149679  protein:proph:183386    protein:plasmid:147856
bacteria_1  1   1   0
bacteria_2  0   1   0
bacteria_3  0   1   1
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask a question.

Comment: You are posting very similar questions. I suggest you to try to get some magistery in either perl, awk or python, as well as study the answers you are given. Otherwise you will always depend on people answering your specific problem.

Comment: That's true fedorqui. I would like to have some time to study the answers people give to me, specially perl ones, one of my weak points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way with `GNU awk`:

```
awk '{
    header[$2]++; 
    bacteria[$1]++; 
    map[$1,$2]++
}
END { 
    x=asorti(header,header_s); 
    for(i=1;i<=x;i++) { 
        printf "\t%s\t", header_s[i]   
    }
    print ""
    y=asorti(bacteria,bacteria_s); 
    for(j=1;j<=y;j++) { 
        printf "%s\t\t", bacteria_s[j]; 
        for (z=1;z<=x;z++) {
            printf "%s\t\t\t\t", (map[bacteria_s[j],header_s[z]])?"1":"0"
        } 
    print ""
    } 
}' file
        protein:plasmid:147856          protein:plasmid:149679          protein:proph:183386
bacteria_1              0                               1                               1
bacteria_2              0                               0                               1
bacteria_3              1                               0                               1
```

Here is a solution with regular `awk`:

```
awk '
!is_present[$1]++ {bacteria[++x] = $1}
!is_present[$2]++ {protein[++y] = $2}
{map[$1,$2]++}
END { 
    for(i=1; i<=y; i++) {
        printf "\t%s\t", protein[i]
    } 
    print ""; 
    for(j=1; j<=x; j++) { 
        printf "%s\t\t", bacteria[j]; 
        for(a=1; a<=y; a++) { 
        printf "%s\t\t\t\t", (map[bacteria[j], protein[a]])?"1":"0"
        }
    print ""
    }
}' file
```

Comment: awk: calling undefined function asorti
 input record number 6, file 1
 source line number 7

Comment: @popnard As I mentioned in the solution, this requires `GNU` variant of `awk`. Are you on `solaris` or `mac`?

Comment: @popnard Added an `awk` solution since you don't have `GNU awk`

Comment: I'm on mac, sorry, but thanks for adding both versions. It's working fine, just added some customisation to  be only one separated.

Answer (score 0):

Quick `python` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import fileinput
from collections import defaultdict

output = defaultdict(list)
proteins = set()

for line in fileinput.input():
    bacteria, protein = line.strip().split()
    proteins.update([protein])
    output[bacteria].append(protein)

# Print header
print ' '*12,
for header in sorted(proteins):
    print '{:25}'.format(header),
print

# Print table
for key in output:
    print '{:12}'.format(key),
    for header in sorted(proteins):
        if header in output[key]:
            print '{:22}'.format(1),
        else:
            print '{:22}'.format(0),
    print
```

Outputs:

```
$ python table.py inputfile
             protein:plasmid:147856    protein:plasmid:149679    protein:proph:183386
bacteria_2                        0                      0                      1
bacteria_3                        1                      0                      1
bacteria_1                        0                      1                      1
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "table.py", line 11, in <module>
    bacteria, protein = line.strip().split()
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack

Comment: @popnard yup that is what happens when your actual input file looks different to the example file you posted.... I'm guessing your actual input contains blank lines?

Comment: I just pasted a tab-separated table and applied 'code' format to it. Automatically replaces my tabs with spaces.